# Test Snap Web Framework Handler

Tags: haskell, types, integration-testing, haskell-snap-framework

I want to write little integration tests for my Snap web handlers but I am stuck. Here is the scenario. I have a Snap web handler that (run-of-the-mill style) CRUDs up a type and it looks something like this:

```
create :: AppHandler ()
create = method POST $ do
         lastName  <- decodeUtf8 . fromJust <$> getParam "lastName"
         firstName <- decodeUtf8 . fromJust <$> getParam "firstName"
         createPerson $ Person firstName lastName
         modifyResponse (setResponseCode 204)
```

The `Snap.Test` module has some things to help build up a request and I use it to make a request for my handler:

```
createOwnerReq :: RequestBuilder IO () 
createOwnerReq = postUrlEncoded "host/person/create" $
                 fromList [ ("firstName", ["Greg-Shaw"])
                          , ("lastName",  ["Snoy'Sullivan"])
                          ]
```

Here's the problem, I want to make a TestUnit TestCase for this handler so I need the run the handler on the `createOwnerReq` request. The module `Snap.Test` provides:

```
 runHandler :: MonadIO a => RequestBuilder m () -> Snap a -> m Response
```

so

```
 ... do 
     resp <- runHandler createOwnerReq ???
```

But wait!!! My request handler is of type `AppHandler ()` but `runHandler` requires a Handler of type `Snap a`.
How do I lift my `AppHandler` type into the `Snap` monad? Help please, this is kind of trippin' me out.

Comment: Is `AppHandler` a type you defined? I've looked around online, but have not seen it anywhere else.

Comment: `type AppHandler = Handler App App` ...its a synonym that is shown in the snap tutorial on the Snap web site. Type `Handler b v` is an instance of `MonadSnap`.

Comment: I thought it was something like that. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: Have you tried to just use `return create`: the type system might handle it for you... Anyway, can you post a full script so we can run it locally and debug it, please?

Comment: Ibolla, `return create` did the trick. I am not sure I understand why however. `return` is of type `a -> m a`. I'm at a loss. Where do I look to brush up on this transformer stuff. I've wen't over Monad Transformers Step by Step a few time now. Better have at it again.

Answer (score 1):

Ibolla's `return create` trick probably doesn't do what you want.  It compiles correctly because runHandler takes a `Snap a` which will work on a Snap action with any return value.  `return create :: Snap (AppHandler ())`, which is very different from the `Snap ()` that you were probably expecting.

We are working on a Snap.Snaplet.Test equivalent that will wrap the runHandler function provided by Snap.Test to allow you to test Handlers.  This will probably be included in the 0.10 release of the snap package.

In the interim, you can solve the problem manually by using [runSnaplet](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap/0.9.2.2/doc/html/Snap-Snaplet.html#v%3arunSnaplet) to convert your `SnapletInit` into a `Snap ()` action that can be passed to Snap.Test.runHandler.  This won't let you test an individual `Handler`, but it will let you test any of the routes defined in your application's initializer.

EDIT: In snap-0.10, we added [test support for snaplets](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap/0.10.0/doc/html/Snap-Snaplet-Test.html).